# PyDev JYTHONPATH in runtime of a application

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am trying to integrate PyDev to a eclipse application with several plugin dependencies. Even though my first goal was to access all classes of the plugin dependencies in runtime via Jython, I could not achieve this.

On the other hand, in runtime, if I add ${ECLIPSE_HOME}\plugins* to my project (which has PyDev config) to get all the plugins in '.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins', I get the following error:

[image: My project config which has PyDev scripts]

`Invalid external source folder specified: C:\*******\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\*                       Unknown  PyDev Project Error`

Even if I get this error, when I run my script and import the classes, it works without an issue. My run configuration for Jython run (as you can see, it still detects plugins/* as path) :

[image: Here it automatically detects .metadata]

Now, the main problem is, the auto-completion functionality does not work with these settings. I tried to add same path to Jython Inerpreter libraries, but since there is no way to put * in the end, I had to select all of them manually. In this case, JYTHONPATH becomes so long and yields following error:

`Cannot run program "C:\****\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre\bin\javaw.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The file name or extension is too long"`

I have several questions actually since I do not have much experience in eclipse, but the most importrant one for now is: Is there a way to make PyDev automatically detect all the classes in the plugin dependencies of my application as soon as I start it with Eclipse Application run configuration, without any further settings?